# increase the width of Crystal Reports in c# windows applicaton

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, width

I'm new to crystal report in c# windows application and i want to know how i can increase the width of the crystal report which is fixed to A4 size.

Comment: Are you using the version of CR that comes with Visual Studio 20xx?

Comment: Don't forget to update your questions by marking answers that were correct.

Comment: Beware: if you decrease the width of the paper, you run the risk of truncating fields on the right side of the report--Crystal Reports doesn't scale.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
myReport.PrintOptions.PaperSize = PaperSize.PaperB4;
```

myReport is the Crystal Report you created.

You may use any option available for papersize other than PaperB4.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Trying creating Crystal Report in `landscape view`.